# why I cannot write into file using CGI script

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

When I write some data into a file like example 1, it is fine. But when I try to write some data into a file using Web browser as exampl 2, it is failed.Any suggestion will be appreciated!

example1:(It works fine)

```html
cat > /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py   <<"EOF"
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
open('/tmp/1.txt', 'w').write('abcdef')

EOF
chmod 755 /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py
python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py
```

---

```html
example 2:
cat  > /var/www/html/1.html <<"EOF"
<html>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                     action="/cgi-bin/hello.py" method="post">
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
EOF

cat > /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py   <<"EOF"
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
open('/tmp/1.txt', 'w').write('abcde')
EOF
chmod 755 /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py
http://172.29.20.163/1.html
```

I hope to trigger running python script using web browser (click Submit) like above, but it doesnot work. Something missed?